# Cellulose acetate membrane filters vs. glass microfiber filters

Tags: microbiology

1. At equivalent pore sizes and pressures, which exhibits faster flow rates, cellulose acetate membranes or glass microfiber filters?
2. I know cellulose acetate exhibits low protein binding, but what about glass microfibers? Would they be suitable when protein recovery is essential?

Comment: This might be relevant: how big are the proteins that you want to filter?

Comment: @GoodGravy ~270kDa

Answer (score 1):

1. It would also depend on the pore densities and pressure resistance.
2. Silica is used for gel filtration chromatography to separate proteins. This can be achieved when proteins do not have affinity to silica, and most of proteins could be analyzed with silica gel. Silica and grass are similar materials. However, glass and silica have negative charges on the surface. Under low ionic strength condition, positive charged proteins or positive charged surface of proteins may bind to glass. Cellulose acetate does not have charge but it is hydrophilic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not been able to find any data on pressure resistance for the filters I'm looking at; do you know if it can be said as a general rule of thumb that glass microfibers typically exhibit faster flow rates than cellulose acetate membranes or vice versa? As in is one typically faster than the other or is it just a crap shoot without knowing the resistance?